# How can I either fetch a CSRF token or send POST data through webbrowser

Tags: post, authentication

So what I'm trying to do is to login to a website, and then make a POST request. I've tried just making a webbrowser, and simply logging in there, then submitting the POST data with a button. I'm not sure if it isn't working this way because it's not being sent through webbrowser1 or because I'm not submitting the POST data correctly. Here was the code to submit the POST data.

```
           HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("url");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = "postdata";
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        StreamWriter stOut = new
        StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(postData);
        stOut.Close();
```

I also tried just logging in with one button, then with another button, submitting this POST data, but the problem is that it needs the CSRF token inside the POST request. Here is what I had so far.

```
            string formUrl = "loginurl"; 
        string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={2}", "user", "pass", "token");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
```

What would be the best way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding to the "ajax:before" event in jquery to transparently add in a parameter for the CSRF token before sending off. How you would add the CSRF token in is dependent on what web framework you're using.